# Is there a tool that shows code moving?

Tags: software-development, diff

I moved a piece of code into a new method and I would like to see that in a visual manner. meld and patch just shows a piece of code got deleted and a new piece of code got added.

What tool could I use? Cross-platform strongly preferred.

Answer (score -2):

I will not give you any recommendation tools right now (I will update my answer soon). But, you can try **[Github Gist](http://github.com)** first. The **Github Gist** has a *revision features* that will show you about the codes either added or removed. See one of the public gist [here](https://gist.github.com/facebook/309210/revisions) from [Facebook](http://github.com/facebook). You can view both of green and red bar. The green bar indicates the *added code* and red bar indicates the *removed code*. Actually, this feature lacks of visualization as your expectation.

Another way that you can know the code moving is **comparing the files and folders**. I found on the internet, there was a diff tool you can try. This is one of the example, **[Diff Between](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/02/comparing-files-and-folders-within-your-ide/)** from **JetBrains**. Given the visualization of diff tool here below:

[image: Diff Between]

There are a lot of diff tool that supports an IDE out there.

Comment: That does not show code moved from where to where.

Comment: The screenshot says "deleted" "changed" "inserted" but not "moved".

Comment: sorry, I have missunderstood you question. My answer above doesn't meet your expectation. Sorry.